# Workflow error in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, office-365

I am having this error in Sharepoint Online when I run a workflow to create an Enterprise Project from a list The details of the error was

> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.
>   Details of last request: HTTP Forbidden to
>   https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/WorkflowActivities/CreateProjectFromListItem(webId='923e34ac-7127-4707-b6e1-83ac3235ef67',listId='a352ed9d-3b99-4405-b2a3-2fc3c2678335',itemId='2',eptId='09fa52b4-059b-4527-926e-99f9be96437a')
>   Correlation Id: f9d2736f-8a66-4425-a5cc-cb30adf980ff Instance Id:
>   3e7695ad-5913-4bb0-b6c8-cbf29e4e877a
>
> PJClientCallableException: GeneralSecurityAccessDenied
>   GeneralSecurityAccessDenied

I tried changing my workflow to just send an email to check whether there is something wrong with the workflow but emailing work I suspect it has something to do with the workflow engine service user (if there is such a thing) trying to create and Enterprise Project.

I and the admin so I have the full access but for some reason the workflow is running as a different user on my behalf.

It is a simple workflow and it looks like this

[image]

And the list looks like this with its mapping with the Project Web App Fields

[image]

Any reasons why this is happening? How do I resolve the issue? If its a workflow service user what is the user that I can give full access to creating Enterprise Projects

Comment: The workflow will run as the current user. Are you sure your account has the correct permissions to create a project?